# PRAGMA recursive_triggers won't disable recursive triggers

Tags: sqlite

I do not understand trigger recursion in SQLite 3.8.6.

From my understanding setting `PRAGMA recursive_triggers` to `0` should prevent a trigger from triggering another one.

But here is an example of what actually happens for me:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA recursive_triggers;
0
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t1(a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT);
sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER on_insert AFTER INSERT ON t1
   ...> BEGIN
   ...>     UPDATE t1 SET b="c" WHERE rowid=NEW.rowid;
   ...> END;
sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER on_update_b AFTER UPDATE OF b ON t1
   ...> BEGIN
   ...>     SELECT RAISE(fail,"triggered update b!");
   ...> END;
sqlite> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES("a","b","c");
Error: triggered update b!
```

I probably misunderstood something...

Is it possible to prevent the `on_update_b` trigger to be triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These triggers are not recursive.

A trigger is recursive if it triggers itself (directly or indirectly).
This would be the case if `on_update_b` would execute an UPDATE or INSERT.

Comment: ok, thanks. can i prevent trigger `on_insert` to trigger trigger `on_update_b` (i want this trigger to be triggered by the user only)?

Comment: The trigger can read data from the database (which does not help your), and inspect the NEW.xxx values. You'd need some special value in some column.